# Powershell access HTML frames

Tags: html, powershell

I've been trying to create a powershell script to automate something in my router's website but I can't really navigate through the sites frames and framesets, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```bsh
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true # Make it visible
$ie.Navigate("http://192.168.1.1")
While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}
$usernamefield = $ie.document.getElementByID('userName')
$usernamefield.value = "admin"
$passwordfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('pcPassword')
$passwordfield.value = "admin"
$Link = $ie.document.getElementByID('loginBtn')
$Link.click()
$Frame1a = $ie.document.getElementByID("topFrame") 
$Frame2a = $Frame1a.contentWindow
$Frame3a = $Frame2a.document
$Frame1b = $Frame3a.getElementByID('bottomLeftFrame')
$Frame2b = $Frame1b.contentWindow
$Frame3b = $Frame2b.document
$thing = $Frame3b.getElementsByTagName('a') | where-object {$_.innerText -eq 'Wireless'}
```

This is the code I have so far, but when it gets to `$Frame1b = $Frame3a.getElementByID('bottomLeftFrame')` I get an error message saying: "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."

After I get this frame thing to work, I'd need it to click a hyperlink, if anyone knows how to do that please tell me, I've tried before but it didn't work. I've also tried different languages before, python, VBS, but I got the furthest with powershell.

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Looks like some of the elements are $null... Whats the content of $Frame2a ? Somewhere in your pipeline powershell cant read the IE elements, either because your code is buggy (70%) or because its a limit in your envirionment (30%). If you want to control a browser, generally better use selenium (or pupeteer) but reading all with powershell may be perfectlly fine in this case. theres also a selenium module available which is based on the c# selenium module. controlling browsers is tricky. If you need some entry point, the selenium ide maybe a good start how the navigation works in your case.

Comment: Do I need to go through all the frames to click a hyperlink though? Can't I tell it to just click it right away? That would make my life 1000x easier... If not I might try selenium, that's my last hope.

Comment: Yes, probably you need to activate the correct frame before you can click the element

Comment: Oh well, Selenium it is then. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue in the past. I solved it like this:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true # Make it visible
$ie.Navigate("http://192.168.1.1")
While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}
$usernamefield = $ie.document.getElementByID('userName')
$usernamefield.value = "admin"
$passwordfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('pcPassword')
$passwordfield.value = "admin"
$Link = $ie.document.getElementByID('loginBtn')
$Link.click()
start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500

#Click Wireless
$oFrameLeft=$ie.document.parentwindow.frames['bottomLeftFrame'].document
$oWireless =  $oFrameLeft.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName('a') | where-object {$_.innerText -eq 'Wireless'}
$oWireless.click()
```